# Selecting an option based on Integer value?

Tags: c#, math, if-statement

This is C#

I'm using a variable that is calculated randomly every few seconds to spawn entities, it's a number that is randomly generated between 0 and 100. Currently my system uses a bunch of if/else statements in order from the most rare chance, to the most common.

If the dice rolls at 32, and an entity has a 35% chance to spawn, it will spawn instead of a more common entity that spawns, lets say 70% of the time. However, doing this in tons of if/else statements looks very ugly and I'm sure there is another way.

Any suggestions?

Psuedo of what I'm doing

```
int dice = RandomNumber(0-100);
if(dice < 35) SpawnEntity(Gem);
else
if(dice < 60) SpawnEntity(Crate);
```

This gets, very.. very ugly. It does work, but it's ugly. I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would eliminate some of the if redundancy and keep the initialization cleaner.

```
var actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>
    {{35, () => SpawnEntity(Gem)},
     {60, () => SpawnEntity(Crate)}};

foreach(var kvp in actions.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key))
  if (dice < kvp.Key) {
    kvp.Value();
    break;  
  }
```

As Alex mentions you may need use a SortedDictionary or LINQ to order it during the iteration. Also remember, you're not stuck with using `Dictionary`, you can declare your own collection type and have the same initialization sequence by inheriting from IEnumerable and having the appropriate add method.

Comment: Don't you need `SortedDictionary` instead of `Dictionary` to guarantee the order of keys?

Comment: @AlexD I was thinking about that. Either Sorted or just sort it during the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. `switch` statements won't work because `case` labels have to be constant values, not ranges.

If you want to make the code generic, you could define a data structure that holds a range and a corresponding entity type. Then write code that examines a list of such structures to find out which range the random number fell into, and create the corresponding entity. This would eliminate all the if/else statements and make it slightly easier to add new entities or change their ranges. However, if the set of things you're creating is well defined and constant, this isn't strictly necessary.

You could even abstract this further and create a utility function which accepts a set of `Action` objects, each with a corresponding "weight," and which then randomly selects and executes one of the `Action`s with probability proportional to its weight.

```
// Randomly executes one of the given actions (KVP values). The probability
// of a given action being chosen is proportional to its weight (KVP key).

public static void RandomlyExecute(
    Random random,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<double, Action>> choices)
{
    double totalWeight = Enumerable.Sum(choices, choice => choice.Key);
    double x = random.NextDouble() * totalWeight;
    double y = 0;

    foreach (var choice in choices)
    {
        y += choice.Key;
        if (x <= y)
        {
            choice.Value();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```